# Issues with Analytic function in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, analytic-functions

since June 2nd we are having issues with analytic functions. when the query (not the partitions) passes a certain size the query fails with the following error:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be
>   executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 125% of limit. Top memory
>   consumer(s): analytic OVER() clauses: 97% other/unattributed: 3% . at
>   [....]

has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Hello, if you find my answer useful, please upvote/accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery chooses several parallel workers for `OVER()` clauses based on the size of the tables being run upon. We can see resources exceeded error, when too much data are being processed by workers that BigQuery assigned to your query.

I assume that this issue could come from the `OVER()` clause and the amount of data used. You'll need to try to tune a bit on your query script (specially on the `OVER()` clauses) as it is said in the error message.

To read more about the error, take a look to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#resourcesExceeded).

That's what would help is [Slots](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots) - unit of computational capacity required to execute SQL queries:

> When you enroll in a flat-rate pricing plan, you purchase a dedicated
>   number of slots to use for query processing. You can specify the
>   allocation of slots by location for all projects attached to that
>   billing account. Contact your sales representative if you are
>   interested in flat-rate pricing.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Answer (score 0):

We were able ot overcome this limitation by splitting the original data into several shards and applying the analytical function on each shard.

In essence (for 8 shards):

```
WITH
t AS (
    SELECT
        RAND () AS __aux,
        *
    FROM <original table>
)
SELECT
    * EXCEPT (__aux),
    F () OVER (...) AS ...
FROM t
MOD (CAST (__aux*POW(10,9) AS INT64), 8) = 0
UNION ALL
....
SELECT
    * EXCEPT (__aux),
    F () OVER (...) AS ...
FROM t
MOD (CAST (__aux*POW(10,9) AS INT64), 8) = 7
```